# C# Timespan Milliseconds vs TotalMilliseconds

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

In the example below, why does the `Milliseconds` property return `0` but the `TotalMilliseconds` property return `5000`?

```
// 5 seconds
TimeSpan intervalTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

// returns 0
intervalTimespan.Milliseconds;

// returns 5000.0
intervalTimespan.TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: @AJM the docs for [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) make it pretty explicit what is what with the examples.

Comment: Just a note that all the components of `TimeSpan` come in property pairs like this, not just milliseconds. `Mintes` / `TotalMinutes`, `Hours` / `TotalHours`, etc...

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Simple:

- `Milliseconds` are the remaining milliseconds, that don't form a whole second.
- `TotalMilliseconds` is the complete duration of the timespan expressed as milliseconds.

Answer (score 86):

Because `Milliseconds` returns the Milliseconds portion, and TotalMilliseconds returns the total milliseconds represented by the `Timespan`

Example: 0:00:05.047

Milliseconds: 47

Total Milliseconds: 5047

Answer (score 4):

This hapens because `intervalTimespan.Milliseconds` returns the millisecond component of the timespan.
In your timespan constructor, you only have hour, minute, and second components, which is why the result is 0.

`intervalTimespan.TotalMilliseconds` gets you the total milliseconds of the timespan.

Example:

```
// 5 milliseconds
TimeSpan intervalTimespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0,0,0,5);

// returns 5
intervalTimespan.Milliseconds;

// returns 5
intervalTimespan.TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

`TimeSpan` has other overloads:

```
TimeSpan(hour, minute, seconds)
TimeSpan(days, hour, minute, seconds)
TimeSpan(days, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds)
```

The `Milliseconds` property returns the actual milliseconds value.

The `TotalMilliseconds` property returns the overall milliseconds including days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`Miliseconds` returns just the milliseconds part of your `TimeSpan`, while `TotalMilliseconds` calculates how many milliseconds are in time represented by `TimeSpan`.

In your case, first returns `0` because you have exactly 5 seconds, second returns `5000` because 5s == 5000ms

Answer (score 0):

One important thing other things don't mention, is that (according to the docs):

> The `Milliseconds` property represents whole milliseconds, whereas the `TotalMilliseconds` property represents **whole and fractional** milliseconds.

That is also deductible from the remarks of `TotalMilliseconds`:

> This property converts the value of this instance from ticks to milliseconds.

This has a huge implication, IMO, because if you want *the most precise representation* in seconds or milliseconds, you must use `TotalSeconds` or `TotalMilliseconds` properties, both of them are of type `double`.